# How to run a business logic when sending data through Domino REST API

Tags: api, rest, lotus-domino

I'm currently starting to design mobile applications with HTML5, Bootstrap and AngularJS. The data is stored in a Lotus/Domino database and accessed through the Domino Data Service REST API.

I saw that a ComputeWithForm can be performed when sending a POST or PUT request to the server, by adding the "computewithform=true" parameter. But is it possible to perform a business logic similar to the classic WebQuerySave agent ? I searched for a while but couldn't find anything.

For now, I bypassed this issue by sending the standard request to the REST API and then sending a 2nd request to an XPage that gets the document by its UNID, runs a standard Java agent (using the runWithDocumentContext method) and sends back an HTTP response to the client. But it's not very satisfying. Is there a more straightforward way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you must be able to post to agent. Data Service API is plain CRUD (imo), so anything more than that - write your own "service"/agent.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  The Domino data service doesn't support anything beyond compute with form.  If your business logic is implemented in Java or LotusScript there's no way to invoke it inside a data service POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `TriggerHappy project on OpenNTF`. It includes a server add-in that uses the Notes C API's Extension Manager routines to trigger an agent when events occur in a database on the server. I.e., uou can capture events that indicate a document has been created or updated, and trigger your agent to run your business logic. Since these events will occur no matter how the document was created or updated, you will likely need to set a special item value via the POST or PUT request, and include a little bit of logic in your agent to check for that item value, run the business logic only if it is as expected, and reset that item value so that the logic doesn't run when some other processs touches the same document.